# Setup Domain with Amazon EC2

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, cname-record

I have domain from name.com and I want to add in Amazon EC2 server.

I got Public DNS ec2-xxx-xx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Can I add A-Record in this DNS ?

When I add Elastic IPs , I can't use ssh and public DNS.

So, how to connect domain to Amazon EC2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a `CNAME` record to make your EC2 server visible inside your domain.

Answer (score 1):

what about the SOA and PTR records ?

should they be ec2-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com. or the mydomain.com. I'm new to dns and got quite confused with this.